# JPA 2.0 & MySQL are not respecting case sensitive table names

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I have a strange issue my ear project:
I have put the correct annotations on my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCTS")
```

But when I deploy my application on glassfish 3.1.2.2, I find that JPA has created the tables with lowercase chars

I am using EclipseLink 2.4.1

Please Help me.

Comment: perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392666/problem-with-jpa-eclipselink-and-case-sensitive-mysql

Comment: no i tried to force the names with the escape chars but it is not waorking, thats why i created this post

Comment: Turn on logging.  I believe you will see eclipselink issuing the create SQL with the names exactly as you have defined them.  Databases are mostly case insensitive by default, and so unless the table/column names are delimited, will appear lower case on MySQL.

Comment: @Chris: afaik, mysql is case sensitive on *nix systems by default

Comment: @DenisTulskiy I believe you are right, but he didn't say which OS he is using.  I believe MySQL is one that will return the table name in lower case on Windows regardless of case it was created with if it was not delimited.  Others like Oracle will return it in uppercase.

Comment: I am using Windows, is there any solution for this issue ?

Comment: do you create schema yourself or eclipse link creates it for you?

Comment: the schema is already created. and it is definied in the config, in the jdbc ressource on gf

Comment: In your initial question you say "JPA has created the tables" and in your last comment you say "the schema is already created". It's not clear what is really going on. :-) If your MySQL server is running on Windows, by default, your tables' names, if created by EclipseLink when you deploy, will be folded to lowercase. This setting can be changed in multiple ways. You might look at the MySQL docs: [link] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html). Also, JPA 2.0 more clearly defines how implementations should handle case-sensitivity and identifier delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution from Brian Vosburgh's comment:
In the windows version of MySQL the names of table are set to lower case. On linux, by default, this configuration is disabled, and the tables'names set by JPA are applied to MySQL without modification.

To make it working on windows as like linux, add the line:

```
lower_case_table_names=0
```

Thank you for your help, specially [Brian Vosburgh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566345/brian-vosburgh.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a property the makes all the difference.
In the EclipseLink wizard (generate entities from tables), third page (Customize Defaults), I checked the "Always generate optional JPA annotations and DDL parameters" option.
This option writes the below annotation in the `Entity` class:

```
@Table(name="TableName")
```

The correct table name letter case will be used.